# ¿Qué widget podria usar - Flutter?

Tags: flutter, aplicación-movil, widget, wireframe

soy nuevo usando flutter y quisiera pedirles ayuda con una parte, no sé muy bien que widget usar he pensado en unos botones dentro de un row o algo así, pero creo que ni estoy cerca de lo quiero, me encantaría leer sugerencias o si alguien me puede ayudar, ahí paso mi wireframe de baja, lo que tendría que hacer esa parte es seleccionar algunos alimentos y esos alimentos deben tener imagen y texto arriba, además que cada selección se quede sombreado o que se identifique que se selecciono, gracias de ante mano.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ni has intentado nada XD. SO está para ayudarte a resolver dudas concretas, no para hacer el trabajo por ti. Te recomendaría que fueras al catálogo de widget de flutter y le eches un ojo a las opciyque te ofrece. Intentes resolver el problema por ti mismo y si no puedes, que vengas aquí con lo que hayas intentado. De todos modos, te dejo una pista ListView.builder.

Comment: Lo que buscas en un gridview

Answer (score -2):

Lo que necesitas es un `GridView`. Para más datos y formas en la que se puede utilizar, visita este link: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/lists/grid-lists

Ejemplo:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const title = 'Grid List';

    return MaterialApp(
        title: title,
        home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text(title),
        ),
        body: GridView.count(
            // Create a grid with 2 columns. If you change the scrollDirection to
            // horizontal, this produces 2 rows.
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            // Generate 100 widgets that display their index in the List.
            children: List.generate(100, (index) {
                return Center(
                child: Text(
                    'Item $index',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
                    ),
                );
            }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Recuerda además responder a preguntas en donde el autor de la misma haya demostrado sus intentos en resolver su planteamiento. Las preguntas que piden recomendaciones o son basadas en opiniones terminan [cerradas](/help/closed-questions).

Comment: En adición de lo que comenta el compañero, me gustaría aportar que está no es la solución correcta, porque aunque podrías montar la cuadrícula de elementos, no podrías añadir los títulos ni el botón, tendrías que implementar una composición de widgetd más compleja.